# Trying to install bootstrap to my angular project

Tags: angular, npm, terminal

As the title says i'm trying to install bootstrap 4 into my angular project running the terminal command:

```
npm install --save bootstrap@next
```

Which is exactly how I've done it every time, however this time i'm receiving this error:

```
npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for bootstrap@next
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.
```

Any one had this problem before? I've tried updating to a newr version of npm but I get this error:

```
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/cacache/node_modules/ssri
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/cacache/node_modules/ssri'
npm ERR!  { Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/cacache/node_modules/ssri'
npm ERR!   stack: 'Error: EACCES: permission denied, access \'/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/cacache/node_modules/ssri\'',
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/cacache/node_modules/ssri' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/James/.npm/_logs/2018-04-11T14_11_56_140Z-debug.log
```

Comment: There is no `bootstrap@next` ... try just `npm install --save bootstrap`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Issue 1:**

`npm install --save bootstrap`

**Issue 2:**

**Error: EACCES: permission denied** error comes when you donot have **permission to install packages** for normal user.

Try with `sudo`,

**`sudo npm install -g npm`**

You should do it as a `root user`

Comment: @JamesRees, have you cheked this?